# <label> element with input inside - hot to get text and input value at the same time?

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a bit of a problem. I have  element with form::input in it. And i want to get lebel text and input value at the same time and pass it to another element as value. 
For ex.

```
<label for="contact">Only contact if the fee is over <input id="jpy" min="0" name="JPY" type="number" value=""> JPY（Include tax）
</label>
```

What i want to achieve is to pass "Only contact if the fee is over 1000 JPY（Include tax)" as a value to another element. 
I know how to get .text() of label element and i know how to get value from input. But i don't know how to get them at the same time in consistent form.

Comment: Fix the use of `<label for=...` first https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-label-for-attribute/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents()`, but a better approach would be to use `label` tag correctly:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  let contents = $('label').contents()
  console.log(contents[0].wholeText + $(contents[1]).val() + contents[2].wholeText)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="contact">Only contact if the fee is over <input id="jpy" min="0" name="JPY" type="number" value=""> JPY（Include tax）
</label>
<button id="button">Get text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint but please tel me more about using label correctly...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click', () => {
  var label = $('label[for="contact"]').text();
  var input = $('#jpy').val();

  console.log(label+' '+input);
});
```

Hope this works

Comment: Well it doesn't

Comment: Yup, it doesn't work like i was assuming. @AnuragSrivastava solution worked like charm. Thanks again.